# how to get year from age, month and day in php?

Tags: php, date

i have the `age = 39`, `month = 10` and `day = 5` and i need to get the birth year

the year needs to take in consideration `age`, `month` and `day`

any ideas?

Comment: Is age in years?  Could you subtract that from the current `date("Y")`/

Comment: use GOOGLE, search about `date()` and `strtotime()`

Comment: date("Y") - 39 it's all you need

Comment: @JorgeFaianca , nope. depends on the month and day

Comment: `echo date("Y") - 39;`  returns 1975.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: If your age is 39 then your birth date was on or before this day 39 years ago.  If it is dependent on month and day, then the current age is incorrect and there's no way of knowing what year the birth was in

Comment: Or I just fail at math, ugh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<?php
  $age = 21;
  $birthmonth = 8;
  $birthday = 26;
  $thisyear = date('Y', time());
  $checkdate = "$thisyear-$birthmonth-$birthday";
  if((time()-strtotime($checkdate)) > 0){
       $birthyear = $thisyear - $age;
  } else {
       $birthyear = $thisyear - $age - 1;
  }
  $fullstring = "$birthyear-$birthmonth-$birthday";
  $fullstring = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($fullstring));
  echo $fullstring;
?>
```

It's a bit clunky but it'll work. It checks to see if their birthday has already happened and calculates off of that.

Comment: this seems to work. ill pick this answer, as i can actually test with different numbers. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I just created a small example with my DOB and it works, hope this is what you are looking for

```
$age = 34 ;
$mon = 01;
$day = 29 ;

$beck_year = date("Y",strtotime("- $age years"));

$dob = $beck_year.'-'.$mon.'-'.$day ;
```

Comment: do you know if `strtotime` will consider today's month and day?

Comment: The idea was to get the year from the age with the current date and then add the month , day to that Year.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on correction to my flawed logic in the comments...

```
if( $month >= date("m") && $day >= date("d")
    $year = date("Y") - $age;
else
    $year = $date("Y") - $age - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one hope this will help!

```
$years = 10;
$months = 1;
$days = 1;

function get_byear($years,$months,$days ){
    $b_year = date('Y', strtotime("$years years $months months $days days ago"));
    return $b_year;
}

echo get_byear($years,$months,$days);
```